# Include / exclude tests with Maven Surefire + JUnit5 from command line

Tags: java, maven, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run the build for [Apache James](https://github.com/apache/james-project/) which has a huge test suite that is running very long due to tests that irrelevant to me, e.g. tests concerning RabbitMQ. Thus I'd like to exclude those and I want to do so from the command line (not by editing POMs). I'm using Maven 3.6.3 on Java 11 OpenJDK. The project uses JUnit5 and maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.2.

Now, I would expect [the following](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#Running_a_Single_Test_Class) to work:

> For example, to run only test methods in the org.example.MyTest test
> class you can execute mvn -Dtest=org.example.MyTest test from the
> command line.

But it doesn't work. In fact, as soon as I set the `test` parameter to *anything* else than an empty string, *all* tests will be skipped. I tried some of the [syntax that is supposedly supported](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html)...

```
mvn package -Dtest=*
mvn package -Dtest=".*"
mvn package -Dtest=\!SomethingFishy
mvn package -Dtest='!MavenHeadache'
mvn package -Dtest='!%regex[.*HelpMe.*]'
```

...but the result is always the same:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test
  (default-test) on project testing-base: No tests were executed!  
  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

I'm running the `package` goal, as it does the full build, but `test` behaves the same. Also tried specifying `-Dincludes=...` / `-Dexcludes=...`, which had no effect at all: All tests are executed regardless and the parameters don't even show up in the output of `mvn -X ...`. This behavior doesn't change when update maven-surefire-plugin to the latest version which is 3.0.0-M5.

Do I understand something wrong here? How can i specify inclusions/exclusions in this setup?

---

**Update:** It looks like this is caused by nested projects and/or James' project structure in particular. If I enter a "leaf project", e.g. `core`, then inclusions/exclusions begin to work:

```
cd core
mvn test -Dtest=HostTest         # will only run HostTest, as expected
mvn test -Dtest=\!HostTest       # will run all tests but HostTest, as expected
```

As suggested by RobertScholte, I have looked at the maven-surefire-plugin configuration, but couldn't find anything that seems to be related to this behavior.

Comment: Have you read https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#test It should be as easy as `-Dtest=!RabbitMQTest`

Comment: It works for me. You need to check your configuration of the maven-surefire-plugin.

Comment: @RobertScholte Does it work for you with the Apache James project, or in another project? I have looked at the configuration there, but didn't see anything suspicious. OTOH, the project is huge and has over 250 subprojects...

Comment: Wow! My first response comment to Robert was deleted. It said "Yes, I have. No, it does not work, it excludes ALL tests, as I have described. Please try for yourself."

Comment: It is most likely a problem with the Apache James configuration. The project is too big simply analyse the issue. Things you can do: ask the apache James mailing list if they are aware of this. Run `mvn -pl :<artifactId> -am -X test -Dtest=myValue` where <artifactId> is the artifactId of the module you are trying to test. In the debug logging look for the value for `test` in the maven-surefire-plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells what you need to know: in project `testing-base` which is the first to run, there's no test matching your pattern, so it fails to ensure you won't have a false impression of success.

It then suggests to use `-DfailIfNoTests=false` option to let maven ignore modules that don't have any test matching the pattern (it's probably what you need).

Comment: `testing-base` is the second project to run and does not contain any tests, so it didn't seem like this would matter at all. But it does, so thanks a lot!

Comment: I just found out [per the docs that `failIfNoTests` is actually `false` by default](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#failIfNoTests), but suffers from [a bug up to at least version 3.0.0-M6](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE-1910) of the surefire plugin. Oof...

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with -Dsurefire.excludes or -Dsurefire.includes, for example

```
-Dsurefire.excludes=**/*Karate*
```

-Dexcludes or -Dincludes (as you mentioned above) will not do the right job.